# scanf a structure from a function, call from same function to scan other structures

Tags: c, function, pointers, scanf

Im trying to scanf a structure from file input within a function, and print it using another function.

Ultimately I need to be able to print out the same information that I would from the code that I commented out, but doing so from the functions I have listed in the function prototypes declaration area. I only un-commented 2 of those so I could try baby steps to get something to scan and print using functions. The functions themselves are located at the very bottom.

To finish the scan_auto function, somehow I need to scanf 2 other structures that are part of the main structure. I assume I need to call the functions scan_date and scan_tank from scan_auto, however I am unsure how to do that properly.

Here is the code I have so far...

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRSIZE 20

/* Structure definitions   */
typedef struct {
        int     month,
                day,
                year;
} date_t;

typedef struct {
        double  capacity,
                current;
} tank_t;

typedef struct {
        char    make[STRSIZE],
                model[STRSIZE];
        int     odometer;
        date_t  manuf,
                purch;
        tank_t  tank;
} auto_t;

/* Function prototypes   */


/* 
int scan_date(date_t *date);
int scan_tank(tank_t *tank); 
*/

int scan_auto(auto_t *vehicle, FILE *inp); 

/*
void print_date(date_t date);
void print_tank(tank_t tank);
*/

void print_auto(auto_t vehicle); 

int main()
{
    auto_t      vehicle;
    int         number=0,
                i=0,
                status=1;

    FILE *inp = fopen("autos.txt","r");                /* defining file input    */

    /* Check to make sure input file is found and readable.  */
    if(inp==NULL){
        printf("Error: Input file - autos.txt - not found!\n");

        getch();
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Vehicle   Vehicle  Odometer  Date        Date          Tank       Current\n");
    printf("Make      Model    Reading   Purchased   Manufactured  Capacity   Fuel Level\n");
    printf("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

 /*******************COMMENTED OUT*************************************
    while(status>0){
         status=fscanf(inp, "%s%s%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%lf%lf", vehicle.make,
                                                        vehicle.model,
                                                        &vehicle.odometer,
                                                        &vehicle.manuf.month,
                                                        &vehicle.manuf.day,
                                                        &vehicle.manuf.year,
                                                        &vehicle.purch.month,
                                                        &vehicle.purch.day,
                                                        &vehicle.purch.year,
                                                        &vehicle.tank.capacity,
                                                        &vehicle.tank.current);

    if(status==11){
         printf("%-10s%-9s%-10d%2d/%d/%-6d%2d/%d/%-8d%-11.1lf%.1lf\n", vehicle.make,
                                                                    vehicle.model,
                                                                    vehicle.odometer,
                                                                    vehicle.manuf.month,
                                                                    vehicle.manuf.day,
                                                                    vehicle.manuf.year,
                                                                    vehicle.purch.month,
                                                                    vehicle.purch.day,
                                                                    vehicle.purch.year,
                                                                    vehicle.tank.capacity,
                                                                    vehicle.tank.current);
         i++;}

     else if(status <11 && status>0){
         printf("\nInvalid Input - The next line of data is corrupt.\n");
     }                                              
     }                                                  
******************************************************************************/ 




    scan_auto(&vehicle, inp);
    print_auto(vehicle);

    /*

    print_auto(vehicle);


    */

    getch();
    return 0;
}

/*********************************************************************************/   
int scan_date(date_t *date)
{
    int result;

    result=scanf("%d%d%d", &(*date).month, 
                           &(*date).day,
                           &(*date).year);

    if (result==3)
        result=1;

    else if(result !=EOF)
        result=0;

    return (result);  

}    

/*********************************************************************************/   
double scan_tank(tank_t *tank)
{
    int result;

    result=scanf("%lf%lf", &(*tank).capacity, 
                           &(*tank).current);

    if (result==2)
        result=1;

    else if(result !=EOF)
        result=0;

    return (result);  

} 
/*********************************************************************************/
int scan_auto(auto_t *vehicle, FILE *inp)
{
    int result;

    result=fscanf(inp, "%s%s%d", (*vehicle).make, 
                                (*vehicle).model,
                                &(*vehicle).odometer);

    if (result==3)
        result=1;

    else if(result !=EOF)
        result=0;

    return (result);  

}
/*********************************************************************************/
void print_auto(auto_t vehicle)
{
    printf("%-10s%-9s%-10d", vehicle.make,
                             vehicle.model,
                             vehicle.odometer);
}
```

The text file (autos.txt) I am using....

```
Mercury     Sable   99842   1   18  2001    5   30  1991    16  12.5
Mazda       Navajo  123961  2   20  1993    6   15  1993    19.3    16.7
```

Comment: Don't you want `fscanf` instead of `scanf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> however I am unsure how to do that properly.

Can you elaborate on what you're unsure? If you're not sure how to assign value to struct member of struct, perhaps this sample code will help you? I combined all of the things together...

Oh, and I changed your `*vehicle` to `*v` to make it shorter and easier to read.
Also, since you're accessing member of struct pointer, why don't you use `v->xxx` instead of `(*v).xxx` ?

UPDATE 1: You asked how to do it separately. Here it is:

```
int scan_date(date_t *date, FILE *inp)
{
    int result = fscanf(
        inp,
        "%d%d%d",
        &(date->day),
        &(date->month),
        &(date->year));
    return (result == 3);
}


int scan_tank(tank_t *tank, FILE *inp)
{
    int result = fscanf(
        inp,
        "%lf%lf",
        &(tank->capacity),
        &(tank->current));

    return (result == 2);

}

int scan_auto(auto_t *v, FILE *inp)
{
    int result = fscanf(
        inp,
        "%s%s%d",
        v->make,
        v->model,
        &(v->odometer));

    result += scan_date(&(v->purch), inp);
    result += scan_date(&(v->manuf), inp);
    result += scan_tank(&(v->tank), inp);

    return (result == 11); // return 0 if true
}
```

Comment: I have essentially already done what you have explained in the commented out section in my code. I am supposed to scanf the date and tank structures separately using scan_date and scan_tank functions.

Comment: Please check the updated answer, is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, that looks like what I am looking for. I implemented your code but how can I print the results from the scan? I need 3 functions that operate in a similar manner. In my code you see at the bottom I started a "print_auto" function, but it needs to call print_date twice and print_tank twice.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it doesnt need to call each print function twice, but scan_auto does need to call print_date and print_tank to mimic the results I would get from the commented out section in my code.